# How to bind attributeGroup with JAXB?

Tags: java, binding, jaxb

I am trying to use JAXB to generate java classes based on some xsd files. I run into a problem which I cannot solve by myself. I just want to emphasize that I cannot modify xsd files. 
So this is the issue I have:
There are 2 xsd files MultiDestScheduleRQ and MultiDestScheduleRS, both of them have similar structure:

```
<xs:attributeGroup name="ResponseGroup">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation source="Description" xml:lang="en">BLA</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:attribute name="MoreIndicator" type="xs:boolean" use="optional">
        <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation source="Description" xml:lang="en">BLA BLA</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="MoreDataEchoToken" type="StringLength1to128" use="optional">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation source="Description" xml:lang="en">BLA BLA BLA.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:attributeGroup>
<xs:element name="MultiDestScheduleRQ">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="QueryType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Journeys">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="Journey" maxOccurs="12">
                                    <xs:complexType>                                    
                                        <xs:attribute name="RPH" type="Type" use="required">
                                            <xs:annotation>
                                                <xs:documentation>BLA</xs:documentation>
                                            </xs:annotation>
                                        </xs:attribute>
                                        <xs:attributeGroup ref="ResponseGroup"/>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The only difference in the MultiDestScheduleRS is the name of the element. When I try to generate java classes I get an error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: 'ResponseGroup' is already defined
```

I tried to fix it with custom binding:

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="./../Validated/MultiDestScheduleRQ.xsd" >
  <jxb:bindings node="//xs:attributeGroup[@name='ResponseGroup']//xs:attributeGroup">
    <jxb:property name="ResponseGroupRQ"/>
  </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

but it only changed the error message

```
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: XPath evaluation of "//xs:attributeGroup[@name='ResponseGroup']//xs:attributeGroup" results in empty target node
```

I also tried

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="./../Validated/MultiDestScheduleRQ.xsd" >
      <jxb:bindings node="//xs:attributeGroup[@name='ResponseGroup']">
        <jxb:property name="ResponseGroupRQ"/>
      </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
```

only to get the first error again (the one saying that 'ResponseGroup' is already defined).

Can anyone help please?

**Update**
I use maven plugin to generate the classes, it is the fragment of the pom

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <schemaDirectory>./src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                  <include>**/*/*.xsd</include>

                </schemaIncludes>

                <bindingDirectory>./src/main/xsd/541_Grammar_Multidest/xjb</bindingDirectory>
                <bindingIncludes>
                  <include>binding.xml</include>
                </bindingIncludes>

                <generatePackage>com.my.package</generatePackage>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxb2/.schema2XjcStaleFlag</staleFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from the XML schema fragment that you have posted where the error is coming from.  I flushed it out a little bit and go a successful class generation from it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema" xmlns="http://www.example.org/schema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:attributeGroup name="ResponseGroup">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation source="Description" xml:lang="en">BLA
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:attribute name="MoreIndicator" type="xs:boolean" use="optional">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation source="Description" xml:lang="en">BLA
                    BLA
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="MoreDataEchoToken" type="StringLength1to128"
            use="optional">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation source="Description" xml:lang="en">BLA
                    BLA BLA.
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:attributeGroup>
    <xs:element name="MultiDestScheduleRQ">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="QueryType">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Journeys">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="Journey" maxOccurs="12">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:attribute name="RPH" type="Type" use="required">
                                                <xs:annotation>
                                                    <xs:documentation>BLA</xs:documentation>
                                                </xs:annotation>
                                            </xs:attribute>
                                            <xs:attributeGroup ref="ResponseGroup" />
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="StringLength1to128">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="QueryType" />

    <xs:simpleType name="Type">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

---

A JAXB implementation will not generate a property for the attribute group, so the binding file as you have defined it will not work.  I have included a small example below demonstrating how attribute groups are treated.

### XML Schema

Below is a sample XML schema with two complex types that reference the same attribute group.

**schema.xsd**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/schema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <attributeGroup name="my-attribute-group">
        <attribute name="att1" type="string"/>
        <attribute name="att2" type="int"/>
    </attributeGroup>

    <complexType name="foo">
        <attributeGroup ref="tns:my-attribute-group"/>
        <attribute name="foo-att" type="string"/>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="bar">
        <attributeGroup ref="tns:my-attribute-group"/>
        <attribute name="bar-att" type="string"/>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

### Generated Model

In the generated classes below we see that the attributes from the attribute group are treated the same way as the attributes that were defined within the complex type.

**Foo**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "foo-att")
    protected String fooAtt;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "att1")
    protected String att1;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "att2")
    protected Integer att2;

}
```

**Bar**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "bar")
public class Bar {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "bar-att")
    protected String barAtt;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "att1")
    protected String att1;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "att2")
    protected Integer att2;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but maybe I didnt explain exactly or you missunderstood. The problem is that I have 2 very similar xsd files: 
MultiDestScheduleRQ  and MultiDestScheduleRS and the attributeGroup ResponseGroup is defined in both of them. This is what causes my issue.  Not the fact that the same attribute group is used in both but the fact that the same attribute group is defined in both. This is why I tried to rename one of them in binding.xml.

Comment: @homar - Does one of the XML schemas import the other?

Comment: @homar - I'm confused then.  If your 2 XML schemas are not related to one another by import/include then the class generation from each will not conflict.

Comment: They have one common include, they are in the same folder and they are included into the same generation goal (check the pom fragment I added)